# Not able to set header when calling test function with grpc.SetHeader or grpc.SendHeader

Tags: unit-testing, go, grpc, grpc-go

I have a function which add something into the grpc header

```
func Dummy(ctx context.Context, request *service.Request) error {
  err := grpc.SetHeader(ctx, metadata.Pairs("key", "value"))
  return err
}
```

This works fine when it gets called with service.

While writing the unit test case for this, it always fails with:

> rpc error: code = Internal desc = grpc: failed to fetch the stream from the context context.TODO

```
func TestDummy() {
 ctx := context.TODO()
 err := Dummy(ctx, &service.Request{})
}
```

I know I can mock `grpc.SetHeader`, but I don't want to do that. Is there any other way we can fix this?

Answer (score 2):

The error happens because there isn't a server stream implementation inside `context.TODO()`. Instead of `context.TODO()` you can use [`grpc.NewContextWithServerTransportStream`](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/grpc#NewContextWithServerTransportStream).

You still need to mock the [`ServerTransportStream`](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/grpc#ServerTransportStream) interface though, but that's not excessively complicated. In fact, the purpose of this interface is exactly to allow testing code that uses `grpc.SetHeader`.

Skeleton code:

```
type mockServerTransportStream struct {}

func (m *mockServerTransportStream) Method() string {
    return "foo"
}

func (m *mockServerTransportStream) SetHeader(md metadata.MD) error {
    return nil
}

func (m *mockServerTransportStream) SendHeader(md metadata.MD) error {
    return nil
}

func (m *mockServerTransportStream) SetTrailer(md metadata.MD) error {
    return nil
}

func TestDummy() {
 ctx := grpc.NewContextWithServerTransportStream(&mockServerTransportStream{})
 err := Dummy(ctx, &service.Request{})
}
```